# HTCondor - Partitionable slot not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, configuration, ubuntu-18.04, condor

I am following the tutorial on
[Center for High Throughput Computing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YcneQBqiCaY&ab_channel=CenterforHighThroughputComputing) and [Introduction to Configuration](https://htcondor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/admin-manual/introduction-to-configuration.html) in the HTCondor website to set up a **Partitionable slot**. Before any configuration I run

```
condor_status
```

and get [the following output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kUEO.png).

I update the file **00-minicondor** in **/etc/condor/config.d** by adding the following lines at the end of the file.

```
NUM_SLOTS = 1 
NUM_SLOTS_TYPE_1 = 1
SLOT_TYPE_1 = cpus=4
SLOT_TYPE_1_PARTITIONABLE = TRUE
```

and reconfigure

```
 sudo condor_reconfig
```

Now with

```
condor_status
```

I get [this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwD9L.png) as expected. Now, I run the following command to check everything is fine

```
condor_status -af Name Slotype Cpus
```

and find **slot1@ip-172-31-54-214.ec2.internal undefined 1** instead of **slot1@ip-172-31-54-214.ec2.internal Partitionable 4 61295** that is what I would expect. Moreover, when I try to summit a job that asks for *more than 1 cpu* it does not allocate space for it (It stays waiting forever) as it should.

I don't know if I made some mistake during the installation process or what could be happening. I would really appreciate any help!

**EXTRA INFO:** If it can be of any help have have installed HTCondor with the command

```
curl -fsSL https://get.htcondor.org | sudo /bin/bash -s – –no-dry-run
```

on *Ubuntu 18.04* running on an old *p2.xlarge* instance (it has 4 cores).

**UPDATE:** After rebooting the whole thing it seems to be working. I can now send jobs with different CPUs requests and it will start them properly.

The only issue I would say persists is that Memory allocation is not showing properly, for example:

[image: in this case]

But in reality it is allocating enough memory for the job (in this case around 12 GB).

If I run again
condor_status -af Name Slotype Cpus
I still get something I am not supposed to

[image: undefined problem]

But at least it is showing the correct number of CPUs (even if it just says undefined).